# Form validation using jquery, php and sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I am trying to validate part of a form, I am stuck on checking the database to see if a company name exists before submitting the form. This is a stripped down demo from the jquery ui modal from with the addition of checking if the company already exists. I am aware of SQL injection and am not doing anything about it just yet. At the moment the form won't submit as I'm missing something, I just don't know what yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I have so far

The JS code:

```
$(function() {
var dialog, form,
    company_name = $( "#company_name" ),
    tips = $( ".validateTips" );

function updateTips( t ) {
    tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
    }, 500 );
}

function checkCompany( o, n ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "crud.php?act=check",
        data: "&company_name=" + o.val(),
        success: function(response){
            if(response > 0){
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( n );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    })
}

function addUser() {
    var valid = true;

    valid = valid && checkCompany( company_name, "Company Name already exists." );

    if ( valid ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "crud.php?act=create",
            data: "&company_name=" + company_name.val(),
            success: function(data){
            }
        });
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
    return valid;
}
dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 350,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Create an account": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});

form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser();
});
$( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

The php side (crud.php):

```
include 'connection.php';
$action = $_GET['act'];
if(isset($_POST['company_name'])){
  $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
}
switch($action){
case 'create':
    $q = "INSERT INTO company_info (company_name) VALUES
        ('".$company_name."')";
    mysql_query($q);
    break;
case 'check':
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT company_name FROM company_info WHERE company_name = "'.$company_name.'"');
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $num;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CheckCompany returns nothing.  You are returning true or false from success but that goes nowhere.

You need an outer deferred so you can return something from your ajax success, back through checkcompany out to your call.

Basically, checkcompany is called and exits/returns normally.  SOme time later, the success function runs but that is independent because it's async.  It's not part of your checkcompanmy function.

Ideally, you should trigger an event on ajax success that your element subscribes to.

Examples from comment below:

```
checkCompany(o,n) {
  var retval = false;
  $.ajax({
     sync : true,
     success: function(data) {
        retval = true;
      }
  });
  return retval;
}
```

OR asynch:

```
checkCompany(o,n) {
  $.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
      $("#ID").trigger('ajsuccess.company');
    }
  });
}
```

OR using returned promise:

```
if (valid) {
  checkCompany().done(function() {
    do the secondary ajax call in here
  }
}

checkCompany(o,n) {
  return $.ajax();
}
```

Comment: No, you need to trace with me...  Your validator calls CheckCompany.  Checkcompany enters, sets up the ajax call and defines the callback, then CheckCompany EXITS back to the outer script that called it.  The return true or false in ajax success means nothing to your outer validation code because it's already run.  You can either a) return the ajax query as a promise and drop a .done() on the call like CheckCompany.done() that can return true or false out of itself, or you can trigger an event on your element from the ajax success.

Comment: The only other option is to run the ajax query sync and set a variable declared outside of the ajax success which you can return from checkCompany

Comment: I added a variable outside the ajax, have I done this correctly, its a bit difficult to follow my code, couldnt work out how to format correctly. `var retval = false;   
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "crud.php?act=check",  
data: "&company_name=" + o.val(),  
sync: true,  
success: function(data){  
if(data > 0){  
o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );  
updateTips( n );  
} else {  
retval = true;  
}  
}  
});  
return retval;`